# Wicket dynamicly add data from database to page

Tags: html-table, wicket

I'm trying to add some data into page from database, after applying "filter"

After submit form, candidate list is update and I want to push this changes into page.

How can I do this in wicket ?

.java file

```
public class SearchCandidate extends WebPage {
    private SearchCandidateModel searchCandidateModel = new SearchCandidateModel();
    private List<CandidateEntity> candidate = new ArrayList();

    public SearchCandidate(PageParameters p) {
        super(p);

        final TextField<String> firstName = new TextField<>("first_name", new PropertyModel<String>(searchCandidateModel, "firstName"));    //Filter

        final DataView dataView = new DataView("simple", new ListDataProvider(candidate)) {
            public void populateItem(final Item item) {
                final CandidateEntity user = (CandidateEntity) item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("firstName", user.getFirstName()));
            }
        };
        Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("step1") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {
                candidate = databse.findCandidate(searchCandidateModel.getFirstName());
                //UPDATE TABLE
            }
        };
        form.add(firstName);
        add(form);
        add(dataView);
    }

}
```

html file:

```
<form wicket:id="step1">
    <input wicket:id="first_name" type="text" size="30"/>
</form>

<table cellspacing="0" class="dataview">
    <tbody>
    <tr wicket:id="simple">
        <td><span wicket:id="name">Test ID</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make you DataProvider - dynamic:

```
new ListDataProvider() {
  @Override protected List getData() {
    if (noFilter) return emptyList
    else return database.getList(filter)
  }
}
```

This way the provider will always load the data according to your data filter.

For more information about static vs. dynamic models/providers check:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models#WorkingwithWicketmodels-DynamicModels

Comment: Thanks. I solve this few hours after posting this post. - same as you write (y)